# New Flutter Project not opening in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to open a new Flutter Project in VS Code using the command palette. The output shows:
"flutter create --ios-language swift --android-language kotlin .
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash’: No such file or directory
exit code 127
"
How to solve it?

Comment: Have you correctly set the path for the flutter bin in the bash profile file using your terminal

Comment: Please write flutter doctor and then share your output

Answer (score 0):

> /usr/bin/env: ‘bash’: No such file or directory exit code 127

The VS Code extension tries to spawn Flutter using shell execution, and is trying to run `bash`. I suspect your `PATH` environment variable has been set incorrectly and no longer contains a valid `bash` binary.